# Unable to see abstract base class methods via child class instance using Reflection

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have an abstract base class as below and a child class which extends the base class.Now when I get an instance of the child class via spring as below am not able to see the base class methods although all my base class methods are public ones.
I try to get all the methods of the object(bean) that I retrieved via spring 
I don't see the methods defined in my abstract base class .Can somebody let me know what is wrong with this piece of code?

I am only able to see those  methods which are explicitly defined in the child class.

```
//Base abstract class 
    public abstract class A<K, V> implements C<K, V>,CD<K,V> {
       public final V get(final K key){}
       public final V get(String key){}
       public String getValue();

    }
    //Child concrete class 
    public class Q extends A<Long, XYZ> implements QC,
        CD<Long, XYZ> {
     public Class<XYZ> getClass() {}
     public String getValue(){}
    }
    //Code to retrieve the objects using reflection
    final Object someObject = ApplicationContext.getBean("Q");

          for (Method method : someObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
                        if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers()) && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0
                            && method.getReturnType() != void.class
                            && (method.getName().startsWith("get") || method.getName().startsWith("is"))) {
                            Object value = method.invoke(someObject);
                            if (value != null) {
                                System.out.println(method.getName() + "=" + value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I don't see how you can even compile that code as Q doesn't implement all the methods of A.

Comment: I have only given a sample code to explain the issue .Q implements all the methods of A

Comment: This code piece depicts my problem and has enough code to explain the issue

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis R u able to get the base class methods like public final V get(String key)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91701/discussion-between-sam-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score -1):

It is normal to see only the methods of the class that you investigate, because the Class-Object only contains the information of the class itself and not of its parents. If you want to see the Fields and Methods of the superclass, you have to get the superclass.

```
Class currentClass = someObject.getClass();
while (currentClass != null) {

   for (Method method : currentClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
     ...
   }

   currentClass = currentClass.getSuperclass();
    //http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out the issue .The issue lies in understanding the difference between these 2 methods and using it as per your needs

1.Class.getDeclaredMethods() returns methods of the class you are trying to refer via the class object 
2. Class.getMethods() returns the inherited methods + methods of the class you are trying to refer. In short it will return all the methods of its parent class or any interface it is implementing.Since getMethods takes a client's view of the class, the array will contains all of the public methods, including those defined in the class itself and in its super class and its super-duper class and so on up to Object

So in my case using getMethods() fixed the issue

.